# The Vacisek Model and the short rate process proof of existing hedge / replicating portfolio

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, local-martingales

Given Vasicek model in for short rate

\begin{equation}
dr=k(a-r)dt+\sigma dW_{t}
\end{equation}

where $k,a,\sigma$ positive constant and $W_{t}$ standard BM under $Q$.
Suppose there is a call option

\begin{equation}
X=max[p(T_{0},T)-k,0]
\end{equation}

where $p(t,T)$ is price of the a T-bond at $t$ and $T_{0}<T$.

By definition a replication of this claim is a value process which converges a.s in probability to $X$.
Suppose

$V^{h}_{t}=h^{T_{0}}p(t,T_{0})+h^{T}p(t,T)$

in other words a portfolio of T-bond and T_{0}-bond. I know that $h^{T_{0}}$ and $h^{T}$ can be found as standard normal distribution in the same manner as classic pricing formula for call option.

\begin{equation}
h^{T}=\Phi(d_{1})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
h^{T_{0}}=\Phi(d_{2})
\end{equation}

So that is not an issue but, how do one show that this actually converges in probability to $X$?

Comment: This question might be more adapted for this forum : http://quant.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Cheers I will post it there.